# where can i get content property value for google Material Icon

Tags: css, material-design, font-awesome, google-material-icons

Is there a link available from where i could fetch content value of every google material icon as we have for font awesome icons: http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Answer (score 3):

**Here you can find the `content`(search by name of icon):**
https://github.com/Angelmmiguel/material_icons/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/material_icons_unicode.css.erb#L85-L3265 
**And also here:**https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints

from Icon-Material:
[image]
Search in link that I attach:
[image]
**Using:**

```css
div:before { 
font-family: "Material Icons";
content: '\e8f9';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<div></div>
```

Comment: @Shubhi Sood Tell me for more help

Comment: Do it help you?

Comment: I have found https://shanfan.github.io/material-icons-cheatsheet/

Comment: Unfortunately those haven't been updated in 2 years. :(

Comment: If you find something newer let me know i will update my answer